# android different info window for each marker in google maps

Tags: android, maps, marker

I am using a for loop to make markers on maps based on locations retrieved from database.

I have a layout with two TextViews that i want to fill with the marker's name and address(retrieved from database).

I tried using googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter() but all it did was changing the layout for all markers altogether (which is obviously NOT what i need).

So is there a way to allow me to change the info window of each marker independently?

Comment: When you click on the marker pass the view you want to set to a instance variable and set the view oninfowindow adapters getinfoWindow method. But having different infoWindows for each marker is very heavy lifting for map, best way is to reuse infoWindows

Comment: Please show the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Implement onMarkerClickListener. Get the marker object as follows

```
Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLong)
            .title(string1).snippet(string2)));
```

You will get your marker in overridden method when you click on it.
Get the title and snippet from it as follows.

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MarkerAdapter(getActivity(), marker
            .getTitle(), marker.getSnippet()));
    return false;
}
```

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to show two lines of text is to use built-in support for info window. When setting title and snippet on each marker, you will have them shown after clicking `Marker` if you don't set your own `InfoWindowAdapter`.

If your address is multiline text, then the above won't work correctly and you need to provide you own `InfoWindowAdapter` implementation. When doing that just use `Marker` parameter sent to `getInfoContents` or `getInfoWindow`: retrieve title and snippet from it and put inside your `TextViews` using `setText`.

When having more than 2 texts to show or other data types, it complicates even futher, but if you need it at some point, take a look at this answer: [Android google maps add to marker own tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384643/android-google-maps-add-to-marker-own-tag/16384743#16384743)

Comment: the thing is it's not just two editTexts, i have a few check boxes to show too.so the title and snippet thing probably wont work.

and about passing my title and snippet to getInfoContents, wont that show only the attributes of my last marker (as u said in the answer you linked)

Comment: @MazenElian `I have a layout with two TextViews`. I know it's not a court, but telling the truth, the whole truth and nothing but the truth really helps you get a proper answer. `not just two editTexts, (...) a few check boxes`. You can't have interactive `Views` inside info window. Read this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#info_windows

Comment: I didn't mean to be secretive or anything, it's just that it didn't seem to matter.

And i know that interactive views are not available, i just want to show whether the check box has been checked or not, and also to set the text of the textview as something different for each marker

thank you very much in advance and sorry for inconvenience...

Comment: @MazenElian Posting the code you have now could help. Anyway you can follow the answer I put a link to in the last paragraph or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729264/show-dynamically-to-infowindow-googlemap-v2/16730057#16730057. It will help

Comment: @MaciejGoriski can it is possible from any how or any way to make entry for each marker different infowindow data contain if it can possible then how to i do i have look your answers from all links but did not get infowindow own different view data load