# Android google maps markers with different values on Info Window

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a map with a lot of markers, and I want custom values for the Info Window in each marker.

**For adding the markers:**

```
final JSONArray stops = new File().getStops(lineId);
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < stops.length(); i++) {
        BitmapDescriptor stopMarkerIcon = new File().getStopMarkerIcon(color, Integer.parseInt(stops.getJSONObject(i).getString("sequence")));
        LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(stops.getJSONObject(i).getString("lat")), Double.parseDouble(stops.getJSONObject(i).getString("lng")));
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().icon(stopMarkerIcon).position(coordinate).anchor(.5f, .5f);
        googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new StopsInfoWindow(i));
        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

**The Info Window Adapter:**

```
public class StopsInfoWindow implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    private View view;
    private int i;

    public StopsInfoWindow(int i) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) Controller.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_stop_marker_info, null);
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(final Marker marker) {
        TextView tvLat = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_lat);
        TextView tvLng = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_lng);
        tvLat.setText("Latitude:" + i);
        tvLng.setText("Longitude:" + i);

        return view;
    }
}
```

The problem is when I click any marker, it shows with the same value for all. In this case "i" being the stops.length() - 1;

I think the problem is here:

```
googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new StopsInfoWindow(i));
```

Each time I add a marker (each time I iterate in the for loop) I am setting a new Info Window to the map. Is there any way to add the Adapter to the marker itself instead of the map? That way I could have a new InfoWindow with custom values for each marker.

Comment: https://github.com/ErNaveen/google_map_sample/blob/master/googlemap_sample/src/com/example/mapdemo/MarkerDemoActivity.java

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263097/android-different-info-window-for-each-marker-in-google-maps?rq=1) if it can help you;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use a HashMap**

I'm not sure if this is the best solution but it works. Basically I just added the marker into a HashMap and passed this HashMap to my Custom Info Window class.

**Adding the markers:**

```
HashMap<Marker, JSONObject> stopsMarkersInfo = new HashMap<>(); // created the HashMap
JSONArray stops = new File().getStops(lineId);
for (int i = 0; i < stops.length(); i++) {
    BitmapDescriptor stopMarkerIcon = new File().getStopMarkerIcon(color, Integer.parseInt(stops.getJSONObject(i).getString("sequence")));
    LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(stops.getJSONObject(i).getString("lat")), Double.parseDouble(stops.getJSONObject(i).getString("lng")));
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().icon(stopMarkerIcon).position(coordinate).anchor(.5f, .5f);
    Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    stopsMarkersInfo.put(marker, stops.getJSONObject(i)); // added each marker and 
                                                          // his information to the HashMap
}
googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new StopsInfoWindow(stopsMarkersInfo)); // passed the HashMap
```

**Info Window Adapter:**

```
public class StopsInfoWindow implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    private HashMap<Marker, JSONObject> stopsMarkersInfo;
    private View view;

    public StopsInfoWindow(HashMap<Marker, JSONObject> stopsMarkersInfo) {
         this.stopsMarkersInfo = stopsMarkersInfo;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
         return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(final Marker marker) {
        JSONObject stop = stopsMarkersInfo.get(marker);
        if (stop != null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) Controller.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_stop_marker_info, null);

            TextView stopName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.stop_name);
            stopName.setText(stop.getString("name"));

            TextView stopLine = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.stop_line);
            stopLine.setText(stop.getString("line"));
        }
        return view;
    } 
}
```